# How to create Jquery month select calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I want a jquery month select calender. can anyone give me a website link or steps how to create month view calender like this image. please help me

[image: view of calender what i want]

Comment: what's wrong with that one you've provided on the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle**  : Enjoy this : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/pyS99/

```
options = {
    pattern: 'yyyy-mm', // Default is 'mm/yyyy' and separator char is not mandatory
    selectedYear: 2010,
    startYear: 2008,
    finalYear: 2012,
    monthNames: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
};

$('#custom_widget').monthpicker(options);
```

**Source** :
http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/